# SiteCore DAM assets not optimized

Tags: dam

I am using sitecore DAM for assets management(images and docs). Are the images optimized? When I run lighthouse, it shows the images are not optimized. This https://docs.stylelabs.com/contenthub/4.1.x/content/user-documentation/index.html does not give any info ! Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I think the optimisation provided is not enough. Try to use ImageMagick instead https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET, by creating compressed version of the image on your server

Answer (score 0):

In Content Hub, each asset has a set of renditions that comes OOTB. Typically preview and thumbnails are optimized for web use.

Here is documentation for the OOTB renditions:

https://docs.stylelabs.com/contenthub/4.1.x/content/user-documentation/manage-digital-assets/download/default-renditions.html

Now lets say you needed a particular rendition size you wanted to create for that asset, that is something you can do very easily with custom renditions:

https://docs.stylelabs.com/contenthub/4.1.x/content/user-documentation/manage-digital-assets/download/custom-download-parameters.html

You can even add new default renditions that can be produced on upload of new assets in the media processing. You can make it any size or even specify a new file format output.  Check out this section for more detail:

https://docs.stylelabs.com/contenthub/4.1.x/content/user-documentation/manage/processing/media-processing/media-processing.html

I would also take some time to read up on use of public links:

https://docs.stylelabs.com/contenthub/4.1.x/content/user-documentation/manage-digital-assets/share/public-links/public-links.html